# Multiple Keyboard Layouts and Shortcuts

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, qt

I configured KDE to switch easily from a bépo (french-dvorak) to an azerty layout. I configured it with the KDE interface (`systemsettings`), but I guess it just call `setxkbmap be` and `setxkbmap fr`.
The azerty layout is the default (and the first in the list of the layouts).

However, the shortcuts remains attached to the physical keys: pressing the <kbd>q</kbd> key yields a "q" in azerty and an "a" with the bepo layout.
However, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> have the same effect in both cases (quitting, in most softwares, for instance with `kwrite` or `konsole`). Note however that some softwares (as `firefox`) do the switch (pressing the <kbd>j</kbd> key, which prints a "t" with the bépo layout, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> at the same time, opens a new tab, which is the expected behaviour). [According to this comment](http://kate-editor.org/2013/10/07/multiple-keyboard-layouts-and-shortcuts/#comment-1485), GTK apps do the switching, whereas  Qt apps do not.

**How to make the keys of the shortcuts and the key to enter text coincide in all software**

More precisely, the shortcuts are defined according to the first layout in the list. How to make the definition of the shortcuts switch as well for Qt apps?

Configuration (system):

```
$ kded4 --version
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.38
KDE Daemon: 4.14.38

$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

Configuration (setxkbmap):

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us,fr
variant:    intl-unicode,bepo
options:    grp:caps_toggle
```

(where fr is actually bepo)

```
$ localectl list-x11-keymap-variants fr
azerty
bepo
bepo_latin9
bre
dvorak
geo
latin9
latin9_nodeadkeys
latin9_sundeadkeys
mac
nodeadkeys
oci
oss
oss_latin9
oss_nodeadkeys
oss_sundeadkeys
sundeadkeys
us
```

Related pages :

- [Shortcut keys that are independent to keyboard layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91355/shortcut-keys-that-are-independent-to-keyboard-layout) (the problem is the opposite of mine!)
- http://kate-editor.org/2013/10/07/multiple-keyboard-layouts-and-shortcuts/ (proposes a 2-year-old workaround). According to this page, "the order [of the layouts] defines a priority, and the shortcuts always use the first entry in the list."
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197552 (bug report, that claims that it has been closed)
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32908
- https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/96993
- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=189004 (solution to remap a single key)
- [How do I run a script when I switch between keyboard layouts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94285/101324) could probably do the trick, by triggering a script that changes the order of the layouts.

**Edit:** This question has been opened *2131* days ago, received *three* bounties, 31 upvotes, has 11 favorites, [it is the most upvoted unanswered question as of now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337459/262759), but it wasn't offered one serious motivated answer? I should probably being submitting bug report, but I don't even know what software is responsible!

Comment: I thought there are layouts that are `dvorak + qwerty ctrl` (or evivelent for french). There are others that are full `dvorak`.

However I have just tried with french dvorak, and 2 bepo layouts, and can not reproduce this. I am using debian 6 (Wheezy) with kde4.

Comment: According to `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants us`, the only `dvorak` options available are `dvorak
dvorak-alt-intl
dvorak-classic
dvorak-intl
dvorak-l
dvorak-r`. I guess you were referring to softwares as [dvorak-qwerty](https://github.com/kentonv/dvorak-qwerty). I edited my question, to provide more details.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @RobertSiemer Not that I know, unfortunately… There were 2 bounties offered on that question, already, and still no solution…

Comment: "but I guess it just call setxkbmap be and setxkbmap fr": This is where you're wrong, there's much more than that when you use KDE's GUI (e.g. so they can set the mappings per software, etc). That's why calling `setxkbmap` won't simply do it.

Comment: Ok, @X.LINK, but as I wrote I do the switching from KDE's GUI, so I'm not really sure what's happening behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks, @Quasímodo The issue has already been reported twice ( https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32908 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197552) and supposedly resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be solved on my current set-up:

```
~$ kded5 --version
kded5 5.78.0


~$ uname -a
Linux XXX 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
localectl set-keymap --no-convert <keymap>
```

Which will change the keymap used at startup. Substitute keymap here with the one you'd like to use. Also ensure that you change your other locale information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Magus, but your answer does not seems to solve my problem. I did `localectl set-keymap --no-convert bepo` (as a normal user), restarted my computer, but for instance in Kate, pressing the physical keys `Ctrl` + `v` always paste my clipobard, no matter my current layout.

Comment: @Clément `localectl` sounds like a command to be run as `root`, how about you try that and let us know? (Likely needs a reboot.)

Comment: @Ned64 No, this command, even executed as root, and even after the reboot, does not solve the problem.