# KDE How to switch between 4 keyboard layouts?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, kde4

I have KDE 4.14.2 on Debian 8.1 installed. When I have 3 layouts, switching META+Spacebar works perfectly. The problem begins when I am adding 4th layout, switching  works incorrectly: I'm only able to switch from 1st->2nd layout, when I click switch layout shortcut in other cases (2,3,4) it does not work at all, so that 2->3, 3->4, 4->1 do not work at all.

I found some workaround to this: I have checked spare layouts option, so now I am able to switch between the most usable 3 layouts. But anyways I use 4. I couldn't find any solution of this on the internet. How to fix this?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my Debian 8.1 with KDE 4.14.2. Detailed configuration at (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214273/101324). I guess you should not tick the box below the list of layouts, which is "Dispositions supplémentaires" in French, is that your "spare layout"? [See screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OR07T.png).

Comment: I am not quiet sure if that is spare layouts, but here you can see what is spare layouts: http://kate-editor.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/keyboard-layouts.png And thank you for the replay, I will check that topic later

Comment: So I have it checked, and I have chosen the max value (3) in the text box. I use 4 layouts, and switching actually works incorrectly: it only goes from 1st layout to 2nd, after that shortcut switching does not work

Comment: So, does the proposed answer works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found templorary workaround. Just to use "Alternative shortcut" set as META+Spacebar.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution : untick the *spare layout* option for your layouts.**

You should **not** use the *spare layout* option. This behaviour is perfectly sensible given that option (it is exactly what it is meant to do):

According to some KDE doc ([pdf](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/keyboard/keyboard.pdf), [html](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/keyboard/layouts.html)):

> **Spare layouts**
>
> This option can be enabled only if you have more than
> two layouts.
>
> Spare layouts allow to toggle between small number of
> layouts easily while keeping more layouts handy close by.  For example
> you might use 3 languages:  English, Ukrainian and German but first
> two are used often and third one just occasionally.  In this case you
> can configure  first  two  as  main  layouts  (setting Main  layout
> count :  2)  and  German  one  as spare one - when you toggle with
> keyboard and left mouse button the switch will happen between main
> layouts only but you can always choose 3rd layout with context menu.
>
> (…)

You should probably have a look as well at [this question at superuser.sx](https://superuser.com/a/322246/446943)

Comment: no, it does not work. As I said if it's unchecked, I'm only able to switch from 1->2 layout, when I click switch layout shortcut in other cases (2,3,4) it does not work at all, so that 2->3, 3->4, 4->1 do not work at all

Comment: Did you tried to check it? To check it then uncheck it?

Comment: yes, I have tried a lot of ways, except reinstalling kde :)